# expected an indented block error

Tags: python, excel, text

I have an excel sheet having 4 rows and 5 columns. The last columns has either of the two values ie. completed and pending. All I want is to export the rows having their last column value as pending to a text file. I have tried a code but it is giving error

```
import xlrd

workbook=xlrd.open_workbook('C:/Users/admin/Documents/omkar.xlsx')
sh=workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

def ncols():

print sh.nrows
print sh.ncols

n=0
i=0

file=open('C:/Users/admin/Documents/om.txt','w')

for n in range(sh.nrows):

    for i in range(sh.ncols):
        data =str(sh.cell_value(n,i)) + " "

    if  sh.cell_value(n,ncols) == "pending":

        print  data,
        file.write(data + " ")

    print 
    file.write("\n")
```

Comment: Maybe you should try another code?

Comment: Show your code.  Show what you expected.  Show what you got instead.

Comment: Use [Excel autofilter](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Filter-data-in-an-Excel-table-7d8e9739-2898-4bfe-9d0f-c6204e6e5c8a) and copy/paste the rows out.

Comment: If your code is exactly as it appears here, then the problem is that you don't have an indented block after `def ncols():` and Python was expecting one.

Comment: I just want to have the rows with its last column being pending to be exported to either a text file or an excel file

Comment: Ya you might be correct. But how do I overcome it?

Comment: You mean, how do you overcome not having an indented block after a `def`? Have you tried... providing an indented block after the `def`? It sounds like you need to have a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd

workbook=xlrd.open_workbook('C:/Users/admin/Documents/omkar.xlsx')
sh=workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

def ncols():

print sh.nrows
print sh.ncols

n=0
i=0

file=open('C:/Users/admin/Documents/om.txt','w')

for n in range(sh.nrows):

    for i in range(sh.ncols):
        data =str(sh.cell_value(n,i)) + " "

    if  sh.cell_value(n,ncols) == "pending":

        print  data,
        file.write(data + " ")

    print 
    file.write("\n")
```

**should be-**

```
import xlrd

workbook=xlrd.open_workbook('C:/Users/admin/Documents/omkar.xlsx')
sh=workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

def ncols():
    print sh.nrows
    print sh.ncols

    file = open('C:/Users/admin/Documents/om.txt', 'w')

    for n in range(sh.nrows):
        if sh.cell_value(n, sh.ncols-1) == 'pending':
            for i in range(sh.ncols):
                data = str(sh.cell_value(n, i)) + ' '
                print data,
                file.write(data)
            print
            file.write('\n')

ncols()
```

Comment: Sorry but it is neither giving any output nor creating any text file

Comment: @user3544059 That is because your approach is wrong. Also when you define a function, you need to call it as well. Check my updated answer. That should solve your problem.

Comment: What if I need to export the excel workbook to another excel workbook instead of a text file?? Please help

Comment: @user3544059 You need to ask another question for that. Please accept the answer here if it solved your problem and ask another question which describes your new problem.